# Geometry Right triangles in a rectangle, find the area.

Tags: geometry, area, rectangles

[image: Geo]

Please help, I've been struggling to figure out this problem for too long...

Given the area of rectangle $ABCD = 1200 \text{ unit}^2$, find the area of right triangle $ABE$

Comment: Do you know the length of $AD$? Do you see some similarity criterion? Or Pythagoras, maybe?

Comment: where does $E$ stand for, or where is it?

Comment: AD = 30, since 40 x 30 = 1200..

Comment: E does not stand for anything... its just the angle in the image.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Now, do you see some triangle similarity? can you apply $a^2+b^2=c^2$?

Comment: You can use the fact that the area of triangle $DAB$ must be 600 units squared and the equation $\text{Area}=\frac{1}{2}\text{ base }\times \text{ height }$ where the base is $50$ from $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Which gives $AE$ to be 24. Then you can work out $EB$ using similarity between triangles $AEB$ and $DCB$.

Comment: I know I have 50 from the pythag therm. but i would still have 2 variables in order to find AE correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $[ABCD]=1200$, therefore the area of $\Delta{ABD}=\dfrac{1}{2}[ABCD]=600$. Now, calculate length $AD$ and $BD$.
$$
\begin{align}
[ABD]&=600\\
\dfrac{1}{2}AB\cdot AD&=600\\
\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot40\cdot AD&=600\\
20\cdot AD&=600\\
AD&=30
\end{align}
$$
Using Phytagoras' formula, we get
$$
BD^2=AB^2+AD^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad BD=\sqrt{40^2+30^2}=50.
$$
Now, calculate length $AE$.
$$
\begin{align}
[ABD]&=600\\
\dfrac{1}{2}BD\cdot AE&=600\\
\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot50\cdot AE&=600\\
25\cdot AE&=600\\
AE&=24.
\end{align}
$$
Again we use Phytagoras' formula to obtain $BE$.
$$
AB^2=AE^2+BE^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad BE=\sqrt{AB^2-BE^2}=32.
$$
Thus, the area of $\Delta{ABE}$ is
$$
\begin{align}
[ABE]&=\dfrac{1}{2}AE\cdot BE\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot24\cdot 32\\
&=384.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way to do this:

You can use similarity of the triangles $ BCD$ and $AEB$ which we can show are similar since all their angles are the same. $$\angle AEC \equiv \angle BCD=90^\circ \;\;\text{ and }\;\; \angle EAB \equiv \angle DBC \;\; \text{ and } \;\; \angle ABE \equiv \angle BDC$$ 
Thus all we need is to find the ratio of two matching sides of the triangles to be able to work out the others.

$$1200=BC \times AB=BC\times 40\;\; \therefore \;\; BC=\frac{1200}{40}=30$$

$BC=30$ and $AB=40$ therefore from the Pythagorean theorem we know that: $$BD=\sqrt{BC^2+AB^2}=\sqrt{30^2+40^2}=50$$
Side $BD$ is similar to $AB$ therefore allowing us to calculate the ratio between the two triangle sides as:
$$ \frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{40}{50}=\frac{4}{5} $$
thus now we can find the length of $AE$ simply by multiplying $BC$ (the side of the smaller triangle that corresponded with $AE$) by $\frac{4}{5}$.

$$AE=\frac{4}{5}\times 30=24 \;\;\; \text{ and }\;\;\; EB=\frac{4}{5}\times DC=\frac{4}{5}\times40=32$$
Thus allowing you find the area of the triangle: $$\text{Area}=\frac{1}{2}\times 32\times 24=384$$

---

Indicdently you could also use the fact that the areas of two similar triangles are proportional to the *square* of the ratio of their sides. That is, we know the ratio of the sides is $\frac{4}{5}$ thus the square of this ratio is $ \frac{16}{25}$ so all we need to do is multiply the area of the larger triangle (which we already know is 600) by $\frac{16}{25}$ to gives the same answer:
$$ \text{Area}=\frac{16}{25}\times 600=384 $$